# DateTimeOffset display after daylight savings change

Tags: c#, .net, datetime, .net-4.0, datetimeoffset

I have a question about DateTimeOffset and daylight savings time.  To explain my question lets assume that right now the date and time is:

```
11/6/2010  10:15:00 AM
```

If I run this code:

```
DateTimeOffset myTime = DateTimeOffset.Now;
Console.WriteLine("Local time: " + myTime.ToLocalTime().DateTime);
```

Then I get this result:

> Local time: 11/6/2010 10:15:00 AM

Meaning that the event happened at 10:15 in the morning (my time zone is Mountain Daylight Time (-6 offset)).

So, then I save this DateTimeOffset to my SQL Server 2008 db (as a DateTimeOffset).  The next day I want to display it to the user.  But now daylight savings has expired.

If I run the above WriteLine with the saved off value (from the previous day) what will display?

The offset stored in the database is -6.  But now that daylight savings is over, the current offset is -7.  So as I understand the [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetimeoffset.tolocaltime.aspx), it will first convert my time to UTC time (so it takes 10:15 AM and adds 6 hours (4:15 pm).  It will then subtract the current offset of the local time (4:15 pm - 7 = 9:15 AM).

So if I my math is right, now when I display my event, it will show that it occurred at 9:15 AM rather than 10:15 AM.

This is not good.  I want to store time zone information, but I need my times to stay static in the same time zone.  (Meaning that if the event happened at 10:15 AM in Utah, then the next time I look at it (in Utah), I need to see that it was at 10:15 AM, regardless if the daylight savings time change has happened.

I can't think I am the first one to have this issue.   What do others do to fix this?  (Or do I have the facts wrong?)

Answer (score 6):

No, it won't add the *current* offset - it'll add *the offset at that date* which is still -6. So it should still display 10:15AM, because it knows the *date* involved, and thus the time zone rules in force on that date.

You may well want to store a simple UTC time and the time zone identifier separately, by the way. If you're storing a time zone, then using `DateTimeOffset` won't be particularly helpful over just a UTC date/time. (On the other hand, it's clearer that it *does* represent an instant in time - `DateTime` is a horribly confused type which doesn't let you easily express what you're trying to represent.)

Of course I'd personally encourage you to look at [Noda Time](http://noda-time.googlecode.com) which in my very biased opinion is a rather clearer date/time API than the built-in one... but which isn't quite ready for production use. (We're getting there though...)

Comment: Agreed - as long as you're keeping track of the time zone, storing the DateTimeOffset object doesn't buy you much.  Just use UTC and store the time zone identifier with it.

Comment: @Doug I think he means he stores the offset (as part of DateTimeOffset column), and not actually "the time zone".